# Error resetear contraseña Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hola estoy intentando resetear la contraseña de wordpress desde ¿Olvidaste tu contraseña? Una vez me envia el correo voy al enlace Haz clic aquí para restablecer tu contraseña y me da este error: La clave no es válida o ya se ha utilizado. Por favor, restablece tu contraseña de nuevo si la necesitas.
Alguien sabe como solucionar-lo?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es cambiar la contraseña desde la base de datos. Antes de nada lo que hay que hacer es convertir la contraseña deseada a MD5 (es como WordPress las guarda). Esto lo puedes hacer [aquí](https://md5.gromweb.com/) y te guardas el MD5 resultante.

Luego en la la base de datos, en la tabla `wp_users` (ojo que `wp_` puede cambiar según el prefijo de la base de datos que tengas) localiza el usuario al cual le quieres cambiar la contraseña y en la columna `user_pass` le cambias la contraseña por el MD5 del paso anterior.

Con esto debería funcionar :)

Comment: Vale entiendo lo que dices, pero porque sale ese error?

Comment: @david, los CMS (y la mayoría de aplicativos, de hecho) tienen ciertos requisitos para validar que las contraseñas sean seguras. Usualmente se utilizan combinaciones de letras en mayúsculas y minúsculas, números y en algunos casos, caracteres especiales. Luego, para cambiar la clave debes cumplir esas mismas condiciones y adicionalmente, no puedes usar las mismas claves que usaste previamente. **Por ejemplo:** si usas la primera vez **Mi.cl4ve**, al solicitar un cambio de contraseña no puedes usar nuevamente **Mi.cl4ve**, en su lugar puedes usar **Nueva.cl4ve**

Comment: Puede que la generación de claves de seguridad (no contraseñas) no se esté haciendo bien. Mira que tengas todo actualizado y cambia las claves random del wp-config.php por si acaso.

Answer (score 0):

prueba modificando directamente la base de datos; no me acuerdo exactamente, pero había un método que era tocando en la tabla de usuarios . Siento no poder ayudarte más, pero no tengo ningún wordpress que tocar para investigar

Comment: Hola Jose y bienvenido, gracias por tu contribución en el sitio, te invito a que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tus entradas sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad.